# How can I use try-with and still keep the logger?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

that's my code  and I want use try-with to replace it :
How can I save the logger part

---

```
    public Object valueFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    if(bytes == null || bytes.length == 0)
        return null;

    FSTObjectInput fstInput = null;
    try {
        fstInput = new FSTObjectInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        return fstInput.readObject();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    finally {
        if(fstInput != null)
            try {fstInput.close();} catch (IOException e) {logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);}
    }
}
```

---

---

```
public Object valueFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    if(bytes == null || bytes.length == 0)
        return null;
    try (FSTObjectInput fstInput = new FSTObjectInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));){
        return fstInput.readObject();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

---

in this context ,logger must not be eaten ,
remember the OCP.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a *custom* resource to log the exceptions as: https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources

Comment: You should **not** log the exception message as the log message - log message patterns are interpreted for `{}` arguments. Rather than `logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);` you should log something like `logger.error("error while closing stream", e);`

Comment: good idea,got it ,thanks